# UseState not updating properly with TextInput | React

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, state, textinput

So, im sorry if this is a duplicate but i've read lots of posts and couldn't find a solution to my problem, now I'm here asking for some help directly.

Let's explain the problem, I have in my code a **Modal** that has a **TextInput** and a **Button**. I need to update a State when the text in the **TextInput** changes and when I click the **Button** I need to do some things with the text (but this is not important to the problem itself, so let's just suppose it's a `console.log`). If I open the **Modal** and write some stuff in the **TextInput** it saves the text in the state but when I click the **Button** it prints nothing. But when I close the **Modal** and open it again if I click the **Button** without writing anything it prints what I had written previously. So like:

1. Open the modal
2. Write "Hello" in the TextInput
3. Click the button. It prints nothing
4. Close the modal
5. Open the modal again
6. Click the button. It prints `Hello`

I've tried lots of things but none of them seem to have worked, I'm sorry if the explanation is confusing.

---

Here is some example code:

```js
    function Example(){
        const [modalVisibility, setModalVisibility] = useState(false)
        const [text, setText] = useState()

        return(
            <SafeAreaView>
                <Modal
                    transparent={true}
                    visible={modalVisibility}
                    onRequestClose={() => {
                        setModalVisibility(false)
                    }}>
                    <View>
                        <Button title="Close Modal" onPress={() => {
                            setModalVisibility(false)// closes the modal
                        }}/>
                        <TextInput 
                            placeholder="Type..."
                            maxLenght={20}
                            onChangeText={(t) => {
                                setText(t) // updates the state in theory
                            }}
                        />
                        <Button title="Click Me" onPress={() => {
                            console.log(text) // prints the state
                        }}/>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
```

---

Some of the things I tried:

I tried to change the `onChangeText={...}` to a async function and put a await in `setText(t)` but it didn't work.

I also tried to change the `onChangeText={...}` to a `onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}` but it returned a undefined value

I saw some people saying in other posts to use `useEffect(() => {...}, [text])` but I couldn't figure out on how to use it in my situation. But one thing that I've noticed while trying around with this is that if I write a `console.log(text)` inside the `useEffect` and it printed the actual text, but even after that the button still printed the old one.

---

If you can help me with this situation I'll be very grateful and happy. Thanks for reading :)

Comment: is `TextInput` your custom component?

Comment: @nivendha no it is not a custom, it's the default one from "react-native"

Comment: i tried the code, working fine for me. https://snack.expo.dev/kDsgYNl5t

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is a closure on the event handler

`onPress={() => { console.log(text) // prints the state }}`

The text value over here is bound to the value initially set in the state, hence the state update is not getting honoured since the closure is on the previous value.

You should pass a callback to the onPress handler like this. The handler passed could call the `console.log` function.

```
const onPressHandler = () => {
   console.log(text);
}


<Button title="Click Me" onPress={onPressHandler} />
```

Comment: Can you tell me how would I solve this issue?

Comment: I tried it right now, unfortunately it did not work :( . It still keeps the value from the previous modal. Any idea why?

Comment: So, I tried some other things and found one that did work, it's kinda of a workaround I think actually, but I just made the button use a global variable that was updated everytime together with the state using UseEffect

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const updateText = e =>{
setText(e.target.value)
}

<TextInput 
       placeholder="Type..."
       maxLenght={20}
       onChange={(e) => updateText(e)}
       name="textData"
/>
```

Comment: `e` will be undefined. It should be `onChange={(e) => updateText(e)}`

Comment: You can also just directly pass the function reference and parameters will be handled automatically. Like so `onChange={updateText}`

Answer (score 0):

A. Give a legit initial value to your state
const [text, setText] = useState(””)

B. Your maxLength property has a typo.

C. Give a value property to your TextInput:
value={text}

D. Change your onChange to this:
onChangeText={t => setText(t)}